# ASP.NET pages never stop loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking

We have a problem with many of our website written C# ASP.NET.
The problem is that often a C# page will never fully load from the server.
The page content itself load fine but Images but more annoying Scripts (Javascript) seam to hang and never come down and depending on the content it might lock up the page on Ajax Postback.

This problem is not limited to a single server as it happens on development machines as well as pre production and production servers.

The development machine are just using the inbuilt VS IIS Instance.

All pages that have this problem use ASP.NET Update Panels with varying versions of AJAX Toolkit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons is that your postbacks are being triggered on some events which are either being fired continuously. Another possible cause is that the page life cycle is not getting completed (e.g. infinite loop). If you can post some code, you would get precise answers.

Thanks,
Vamyip

Answer (score 1):

Try using asp.net trace to see which page event is taking longer. Also try using fiddler from client side to see the real traffic and error codes. If you share the fiddler logs I may be able to tell more about what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the time used by all the resourced that are loaded on the page using Firefox and firebug add-on

Anyway the updatepanel doesn't work very well with heavy pages : it posts the whole page to the server and get the whole rendered HTML even if you need refresh a small portion of the page.

if you can you should replace the updatepanel with async Jquery call to the get the the response as JSON and then populate the page as you wish or try to use anothe approach similar to the update panel.

have a look at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/partialRendering.aspx